# How to fix that Firefox renders Bootstrap Thumbnail differently than Google Chrome?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, firefox, thumbnails

Why does the latest Firefox browser render Bootstrap thumbnails differently than Google Chrome? I stuck with getting all thumbnails equal height but can't figure out how.

Setting the `max-width` attribute to `none` fixes the height, but lets the image overflow its parent container. Can you tell me why and how to fix so that it appears in all Browsers like it appears in Google Chrome?

[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zLdbtrq/1/).

**EDIT:** added screenshots *(right-click -> 'open in new tab' to see fullsize)*

Chrome: max-width = 100% (default) - fitting nicely
[image: max-width default value - see how it fits nicely]
Chrome: max-width = none - overflowing parent
[image: max-width cleared - see how it overflows its parent]
Firefox: max-width = 100% (default) - downscaled by BS
[image: max-width default value - see how it scales smaller]
Firefox: max-width = none - overflowing parent
[image: max-width cleared - see how it overflows its parent]

Comment: You want the images to stretch? It would be a matter of setting a specific height at the various breakpoints.

Comment: Like so: https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8zLdbtrq/3

Comment: No, i want the last image to have equal height like its two prev siblings. In my fiddle the first two images have the correct height. But not the last one. The last one must be fixed.

Comment: In no scenario do I see the first two images having the same height in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: See my screenshots in the initial post.

Comment: Why dont you use bg-image and background-size?

Comment: Because these images are links thumbnails to open the fullsize image in modal mode. Beside this fact in good HTML images shall be presented as `<img ../>` and not as container with background. Consider visually handicapped users and screenreaders!

Comment: They can still be links to real images, screenreaders would read title tags. If they are just small thumbs, than there is no need to be an image tag. I suggest you make it easy in 5 minutes, don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

If your images height is fixed to 240px, than one of the solutions is to wrap them in absolute positioned span and use this css:

```
.thumbnails {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
}
.thumbnail span {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    right: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail span img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Check it in [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zLdbtrq/4/), or run the snippet below:

```css
.thumbnails {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
}
.thumbnail span {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    right: 4px;
    bottom: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail span img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div id="slideshow">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div data-index="1">
                                <ul class="thumbnails list-unstyled">
                                    <li class="slide col-xs-4">
                                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail" title="This is ok">
           <span>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/DONm5Ih.jpg" class="shot landscape" width="auto" height="auto" alt="image" />
           </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="slide col-xs-4">
                                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail" title="This is ok">
                                            <span>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TFEAQTJ.jpg" class="shot portrait" width="auto" height="auto" alt="image" />
           </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="slide col-xs-4">
                                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail" title="This is ok">
                                            <span>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WZbs0wI.jpg" class="shot landscape" width="auto" height="auto" alt="image" />
           </span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a nice trick also preventing the images from getting twisted once the dimension is not proper anymore. It appears - especially with the outer right image - that it is kept centered and the wrapping container draws the image more closed. However, this breaks Bootstraps capability to proportionally scale a thumbnail depending on the viewport. I can't stay with a fixed height of 240 on all devices. Did you consider this?

Comment: Guess you can use media queries for height. I have no intention to 'improve' bootstrap, [they](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) have staff to do it (I have other jobs to do). Cheers